# How can i edit "Powered by iCagenda" in joomla 2.5?

Tags: joomla

I am working in a project and I want to edit the "Powered by iCagenda" in joomla 2.5?? i have also edit on previous joomla version but on this i hav'nt find it. Kindly help me if anyone know about this,

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to pay for the Pro version for that:
http://www.joomlic.com/en/extensions/icagenda

Removal of the signature 'Powered by iCagenda' is not an option on the free version.

Technically, you could hack their code (though hacking core code is always a bad idea), or write a plugin to hide it, but that seems a bit unfair on the developers.

(If you are asking about a Pro version, then they have technical support for Pro customers so you are best asking them directly)

Answer (score 1):

You can modify 1 file.
joomlaroot/media/com_icagenda/js/jsevt.js

```
<p><div style="text-align: center; font-size: 10px; text-decoration: none">&#80;&#111;&#119;&#101;&#114;&#101;&#100;&nbsp;&#98;&#121;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.joomlic.com" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none !important;"><b>&#105;&#67;&#97;&#103;&#101;&#110;&#100;&#97;</b></a></div></p>
```

Remove everything and leave only `<p></p>`.
thats it,hope it helps.

ps. you can also modify files that loads that script.
for example file: joomlaroot\components\com_icagenda\views\list\tmpl\default.php
line:
$js_list = "media/com_icagenda/js/jsevt.js";
and after that
require_once $js_list;
remove those lines.
you have that lines in other files, find it ;)

Answer (score 0):

IMPORTANT...if the joomlaroot/media/com_icagenda/js/jsevt.js doesn't work...I found a solution!!!!! :)
Just go to [ROOT]/administrator/components/com_icagenda/utilities/.
There you can find the folder events.
Inside that folder you'll find the file events.php.
There you can find this:

```
public static function isListOfEvents()
{
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $params = $app->getParams();
    $list_of_events = $params->get('copy', '');
    $core = $params->get('icsys');
    $string = '<a href="ht';
    $string.= 'tp://icag';
    $string.= 'enda.jooml';
    $string.= 'ic.com" target="_blank" style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none !important;">';
    $string.= 'iCagenda';
    $string.= '</a>';
    $icagenda = JText::sprintf('ICAGENDA_THANK_YOU_NOT_TO_REMOVE', $string);
    $default = '&#80;&#111;&#119;&#101;&#114;&#101;&#100;&nbsp;&#98;&#121;&nbsp;';
    $footer = '<div style="text-align: center; font-size: 10px; text-decoration: none"><p>';
    $footer.= preg_match('/iCagenda/',$icagenda) ? $icagenda : $default . $string;
    $footer.= '</p></div>';
    if ($list_of_events || $core == 'core')
    {
        echo $footer;
    }
}
```

REMOVE "echo $footer;"

FIXED ;)